# Automatic IEEE referencing generator in LaTeX style?

Tags: texshop, back-referencing

Is there an automatic reference generator that produces citations in LaTeX style that I can use ? I want to use IEEE Citation Style.

I have over 50 references that need to be cited, but typing them down manually will be hassle (looking back and forth on the referencing style tutorial)... 
There are many online, but none produce the results in a LaTeX format.

I don't mind generating it and then copy-pasting the reference into my code, no need for it to be integrated with TexShop.

In TexShop, I'm currently doing this manually such as :

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}

\bibitem{lowry1951protein}Lowry, O. H., Rosebrough, N. J., Farr, A. L., and Randall, R. J. (1951). Protein measurement with the Folin phenol reagent. \emph{J. Biol. Chem.}, 193(1), 265--275.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Have you tried Zotero?  Also, Google Scholar can be used to cite in LaTeX

Comment: @MarioS.E. I will check it now. Google Scholar cites journals only right ?? I have some websites to reference too though

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Google Scholar, but I know it could be used to find the information you need and then export the content into the format just to copy and paste in the .bib file.

Comment: Are you asking about a reference manager? Then we need more information abut the system you're using

Comment: Use JabRef. It has an IEEExplore search functionality and can import the results without actually accessing IEEE with a browser (if I understand corrrectly that `IEEE` in your question refers to IEEE articles).

Comment: Zotero, on the other hand, it's very flexible and easy: you just click in the navigatio bar the website or paper you want to cite and automatically generates a citation that can be exported into the bib file

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I want a  
IEEE Citation Style generator, not a program to access IEEE journals. But JabRef looks interesting. @MarioS.E. I'm not familiar with using a bib file, i'll update question

Comment: Zotero allows you to export in IEEE style, and it has no relation to gaining access to IEEE journals

Comment: @MarioS.E. Yeah I just checked it and it seems to do what I want, except for one problem. I can export in IEEE style but not in LaTeX format, do you have an idea how to do this ? My method : `right click > create bib from item > IEEE citation style & BIB outmode mode & copy to clipboard`

Comment: sure you can, by selecting to export in `bibTeX` and then using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. I'll write an answer including an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd recommend you to get a citation manager, such as [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/).

Then, by selecting it to export citations in `bibtex` format, you should be able to get from it something like this:

```
@inproceedings{espinoza_inverse_2012,
    title = {Inverse Kinematics of a 10 {DOF} Modular Hyper-Redundant Robot Resorting to Exhaustive and Error-Optimization Methods: A Comparative Study},
    shorttitle = {Inverse Kinematics of a 10 {DOF} Modular Hyper-Redundant Robot Resorting to Exhaustive and Error-Optimization Methods},
    doi = {10.1109/SBR-LARS.2012.28},
    abstract = {This paper describes and compares several approaches applied to compute the inverse kinematics of a 10 degrees of freedom hyper-redundant robot. The proposed approaches are based on an exhaustive method and several error optimization algorithms. The algorithms' performance was evaluated based on two criteria: computing time and final actuator positioning error. The mentioned hyper-redundant robot was projected to be used in biomedical applications.},
    booktitle = {Robotics Symposium and Latin American Robotics Symposium ({SBR-LARS)}, 2012 Brazilian},
    author = {Espinoza, {M.S.} and Goncalves, J. and Leitao, P. and Sanchez, {J.L.G.} and Herreros, A.},
    year = {2012},
    keywords = {10-{DOF} modular hyper-redundant robot, actuator positioning error, actuators, biomedical applications, computing time, Equations, error optimization method, exhaustive method, flexible manipulators, hyper-redundant manipulators, inverse kinematics, kinematics, Manipulators, Mathematical model, optimisation, Optimization, position control, redundant manipulators, Robotics, Vectors},
    pages = {125--130}
}
```

Which you should just copy to your .bib file.

Meanwhile, your LaTeX code should look something like this:

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\IEEEPARstart{Y}{our} document here and just to cite: \cite{espinoza_inverse_2012}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs} % your .bib file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

As you can see, it call for the "refs.bib" file by using `\bibliography{refs}`.

The result should be something like this:

[image]

If you are using a project in TeXnicCenter, please don't forget to select the option "uses BibTeX".

Or, as stated in the IEEE Journal Template:

> Reference section can use a bibliography generated by BibTeX as a .bbl file
>
> BibTeX documentation can be easily obtained at:
>   http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/ 
>   The IEEEtran BibTeX style support page is at:
>   http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
>
> OR manually copy in the resultant .bbl file and set second argument of
>   \begin to the number of references (used to reserve space for the
>   reference number labels box)

This last paragraph can be set like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

    \bibitem{espinoza_inverse_2012}
M.~Espinoza, J.~Goncalves, P.~Leitao, J.~Sanchez, and A.~Herreros, ``Inverse
  kinematics of a 10 {DOF} modular hyper-redundant robot resorting to
  exhaustive and error-optimization methods: A comparative study,'' in
  \emph{Robotics Symposium and Latin American Robotics Symposium ({SBR-LARS)},
  2012 Brazilian}, 2012, pp. 125--130.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Just lock those actuators, problem solved !!! :P

Comment: Hahahahahahahahaha

Comment: Is there a way I can export the reference without the need of creating a bib file ?? Such as copying the reference in LaTeX form to clipboard ? Because I'm using {report} and can't replace it with {IEEEtran} as a document class.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I don't mean to be annoying but I honestly got lost clicking all over those links. Did you manually type in that info under `\bibitem` ? Or did the software do this for you ?

Comment: Nope, that's my resulting .bbl file after running bibtex, which can be runned even if you are ysing the `report` class

Comment: @MarioS.E. Do I need to install an extra package to do so ? From the links you posted ?

Comment: No, you just need to rub BibTeX with a .bib file which includes the first part I posted (the one with all the information of the citation)

Comment: @MarioS.E. Okay one final question, BibTex, how do I run it ? Is it through TexShop or something ?

Comment: I personally use TeXnicCenter, but I'm sure you'll find plenty of other possibilities if you look among the answers of tex.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: @MarioS.E.  
Thank you for replying. It seems easier to just use a bib file and import into my TexShop ... Do you know how to edit cite keys through Zotero by any chance ? ( similar to BibDesk)

Comment: Just click over whatever you want to change.  Also, take into consideration you can modify any of the Zotero's preferences by going to its settings

Comment: @MarioS.E. What do you mean click over what I want to change ?? I found a citekey editor online for zotero but apparently it's not stable. I couldn't find a direct way to edit citekeys so that i can use them in TexShop directly `\cite{citekey}`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Ohhh, ok, you can manually change them in your .bib file, but I'm not aware of any way to do this in Zotero